# How to get a difference between two dates?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the difference between two Dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

How to get the difference between two dates using javascript.I need the exact day difference between those two dates.Here is my code

```
function calculateDifference() {
var startDate = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtOStartDate").value;
var endDate = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtOEndDate").value;
return DateDiff(startDate, endDate);
}

function DateDiff(startDate, endDate) {
var a = Date.parse(startDate) - Date.parse(endDate);
alert(a);
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Oh great a new question! pretty sure I've never seen that on SO!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829061/need-a-javascript-to-compare-dates

Answer (score 2):

```
​var date1 = new Date(2012, 2, 28, 1, 1, 1);
var date2 = new Date(2012, 2, 22, 1, 1, 1);

alert(date1);
alert(date2);

var sec = 1000;
var min = sec * 60;
var hour = min * 60;
var day = hour * 24;

var dateDiff = (date1 - date2) / day;

alert('Difference in days: ' + dateDiff);

​
```